# Minimizing an array and value in Python

Tags: python, numpy, min

I have a vector of floats (coming from an operation on an array) and a float value (which is actually an element of the array, but that's unimportant), and I need to find the smallest float out of them all.

I'd love to be able to find the minimum between them in one line in a 'Pythony' way.

```
    MinVec = N[i,:] + N[:,j]
    Answer = min(min(MinVec),N[i,j])
```

Clearly I'm performing two minimisation calls, and I'd love to be able to replace this with one call. Perhaps I could eliminate the vector `MinVec` as well.

As an aside, this is for a short program in Dynamic Programming.
TIA.

EDIT: My apologies, I didn't specify I was using numpy. The variable N is an array.

Comment: We generally say "Pythonic".

Comment: Isn't `N[i,j]` an element of `MinVec`?

Comment: @jwalker No, because `MinVec` is the element-wise sum (*not* the concatenation) of two slices of `N`.  None of the elements of `MinVec` are necessarily in `N`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it's numpy

Comment: Btw, generally `np.min` is preferred over the Python built-in `min`, since it's faster. Also, `numpy` [provides several](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin) `min` variants that can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the value, then minimize.  I'm not sure what the relative time considerations of the two approaches are, though - I wouldn't necessarily assume this is faster:

```
Answer = min(np.append(MinVec, N[i, j]))
```

Comment: That changes the value of `Minvec`, though, and it's not clear whether it will be used again.

Comment: No, it doesn't - from the numpy docs:  [Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Comment: Ah, didn't notice this was numpy -- I thought we were dealing with vanilla Python lists.

Answer (score -1):

This is the same thing as the answer above but without using numpy.

```
Answer = min(MinVec.append(N[i, j]))
```

Comment: Although the OP doesn't explicitly say so, the code implies that MinVec is a numpy array, so it doesn't contain an `append` method.

Comment: He said he was looking for a pythonic way and never specified it was a numpy array. my bad on that.